# Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser

Tags: react-native, webrtc, p2p, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to establish a peer-to-peer video connection between a web frontend and a react-native android smart tv app. I want to display the user's webcam video on the smart tv. I am using an express server for signaling:

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const cors = require("cors");

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: [ "GET", "POST" ]
    }
});

app.use(cors());

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8082;

//here we define the behaviour of the API Endpoints 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Runnin');
});

app.post('/',(req,res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    res.send(body);
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("me", socket.id);
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit("callEnded")
    });

    socket.on("callUser", ({ userToCall, signalData, from, name }) => {
        io.to(userToCall).emit("callUser", { signal: signalData, from, name });
    });

    socket.on("answerCall", (data) => {
        io.to(data.to).emit("callAccepted", data.signal)
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

The signaling is working but as I am trying to display the video the following error is displayed:
[Link to screenshot of the error][1]

Code of the react-native Callscreen component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useContext } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { RTCView } from 'react-native-webrtc';



import { SocketContext } from './Context';
import Callnotification from './Callnotifcation';

function CallScreen(props) {
  const { callAccepted, userVideo, callEnded, me } = useContext(SocketContext);



  return (
    <>
      {callAccepted && !callEnded && (







        <View style={styles.root}>
          <View style={[styles.videos, styles.remoteVideos]}>
            <Text>Video of the caller</Text>
            <RTCView streamURL={JSON.stringify(userVideo)} style={styles.remoteVideo} />

          </View>

        </View>
      )
      }
      <View style={styles.root}>

        <Callnotification />
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(me)}</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code of the Context.js connecting the react-native app to the signaling server:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';

const SocketContext = createContext();

const socket = io('http://10.0.2.2:8082'); // use this to access via android emulator
//const socket = io('http://192.168.178.106:8082'); //use this to access via SmartTv Fire Tv Stick

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [call, setCall] = useState({});
  const [me, setMe] = useState('');


  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {


    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));


    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);

  const answerCall = () => {
    setCallAccepted(true);

    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('answerCall', { signal: data, to: call.from });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    peer.signal(call.signal);

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  /* const callUser = (id) => {
     const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });
 
     peer.on('signal', (data) => {
       socket.emit('callUser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
     });
 
     peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
       userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
     });
 
     socket.on('callAccepted', (signal) => {
       setCallAccepted(true);
 
       peer.signal(signal);
     });
 
     connectionRef.current = peer;
   };*/

  const leaveCall = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);

    connectionRef.current.destroy();


  };

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{
      call,
      callAccepted,
      setCallAccepted,
      userVideo,
      stream,
      name,
      setName,
      callEnded,
      me,
      leaveCall,
      answerCall,
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

Code of the Context.js connecting the web react frontend to the signaling server:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import Peer from 'simple-peer';

const SocketContext = createContext();

// const socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
const socket = io('http://localhost:8082');

const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [callAccepted, setCallAccepted] = useState(false);
  const [callEnded, setCallEnded] = useState(false);
  const [stream, setStream] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [call, setCall] = useState({});
  const [me, setMe] = useState('');

  const myVideo = useRef();
  const userVideo = useRef();
  const connectionRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      });

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);

  const answerCall = () => {
    setCallAccepted(true);

    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: false, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('answerCall', { signal: data, to: call.from });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    peer.signal(call.signal);

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const callUser = (id) => {
    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream });

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('callUser', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: me, name });
    });

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
    });

    socket.on('callAccepted', (signal) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);

      peer.signal(signal);
    });

    connectionRef.current = peer;
  };

  const leaveCall = () => {
    setCallEnded(true);

    connectionRef.current.destroy();

    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{
      call,
      callAccepted,
      myVideo,
      userVideo,
      stream,
      name,
      setName,
      callEnded,
      me,
      callUser,
      leaveCall,
      answerCall,
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider, SocketContext };
```

In my opinion the error lies in the RTCView of the Callscreen but i have no idea how to fix it. Your help is very much appreciated!
Thank you very much!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBh9P.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The library that you are using is probably using the [SubtleCrypto.generateKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) function to generate shared secrets.  This API is "only available in a secure context", which means that it can only be used if the page is served over HTTPS.

Serve your page over HTTPS, and the error should go away.

Comment: Yes, serving over https is working. Thank you very much!